# HashMap iteration/removal getting java.util.ConcurrentModificationException

Tags: java, multithreading, hashmap

i have a HashMap of ClientSocket and Client Object.

i'm iterating throw them using for loop, but sometimes new lines are added to the hashmap and then i get the java.util.ConcurrentModificationException error.
i accutally understand why it happens, but i don't understand how to solve it. i've tried to make a new copy of my HashMap before the iteration starts but yet - i still got the error.

my code:

```
private volatile HashMap<ClientSocket, Client> clientsMap = new HashMap<ClientSocket, Client>();
private volatile HashMap<ClientSocket, Client> iteratorClientsMap = new HashMap<ClientSocket, Client>();
private volatile ClientsMapIterator iterator;

iterator = new ClientsMapIterator(clientsMap);
iteratorClientsMap = iterator.getItreator();

for (Map.Entry<ClientSocket, Client> entry : iteratorClientsMap.entrySet()) {                                                                   
    ClientSocket key = entry.getKey();
    //Client value = entry.getValue();              
    long diff = currentTime - key.getLastOnline();
    boolean isAvailable = false;

    try {
        isAvailable = (key.getSocket().getInputStream().available() > 0);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }               

    if ( diff > keepAlive)              
        removeClientSocket(key);
}

public synchronized void addClientSocket(ClientSocket clientSocket) {
    clientsMap.put(clientSocket, null);                 
}
```

addClientSocket is the function that because of it i'm getting the error.

Comment: Show the code of `removeClientSocket`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found a solution i don't know if it is the best one:

```
synchronized (this) {
            iterateClientsMap = new HashMap<ClientSocket, Client>(clientsMap);  
        }           

        for (Map.Entry<ClientSocket, Client> entry : iterateClientsMap.entrySet())      
        {                                                                                                   
            ClientSocket key = entry.getKey();
            //Client value = entry.getValue();              
            long diff = currentTime - key.getLastOnline();
            boolean isAvailable = false;
            try {
                isAvailable = (key.getSocket().getInputStream().available() > 0);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }               
            if ( diff > keepAlive)              
                removeClientSocket(key);
}
```

i've duplicated my HashMap and iterated it on the copy, and before each iterating process, i'm blocking it to other threads (using the  synchronized title) so it won't be interrupted during the copying

Answer (score 2):

You are modifying the collection while iterating over it. This is flagged as a concurrent modification.

The simplest solution is to use a ConcurrentHashMap which doesn't trigger a CME.

Comment: when i've changed it to ConcurrentHashMap i get the java.lang.NullPointerException at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.put when trying to add new line to the map.
why does my duplication isn't good (nor working) ? i'm copying the current hashmap and iterating on the copy instead of the origina

Comment: You can't add a value value to a ConcurrentHashMap. Why are you setting it to `null` when you method is called addXxxx? Perhaps you can provide an actual object?

Comment: i'm passing only the value as null, the key is set..
it is actually pretty important, it will make the differenece for me later if the client has a Client object (which means he had been logged in) or not...

Comment: I would re think your design. I would just have one thread and one handler object per connection and you wouldn't to maintain the data structure.

Answer (score 0):

The issue seems to be propagating from `removeClientSocket(key);`

where it seems collection is being modified while it is being iterated too.

One way to fix this issue is Pass the iterator to this method

```
removeClientSocket(iterator, key);
```

remove the key from this iterator by calling `iterator.remove()` instead of removing from the collection itself while in mid of iteration.

Seemingly your issue is with multiple threads, either your synchronize access to both add and remove on same lock like:

```
public void removeClientSocket(iterator, key){
    synchronized(clientMap){
      //now remove
    }
}
```

and

```
public void addClientSocket(ClientSocket clientSocket) {
    synchronized(clientsMap){
        clientsMap.put(clientSocket, null);    
    }             
}
```

or use java.util.Concurrent package for automatic concurrency control. You can specifically use [`ConcurrentHashMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html).